# simultaneous download of files - best way to handle it

Tags: android

I am writing an application targeting API level 9 or higher. So, i 
have decided to go with DownloadManager Class that SDK offers. 
My question is 2 part - 
1. When i am downloading a single file, how do i display the progress 
of the download. I see i can get COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES and 
COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR from the querying the download manager 
instance. But i am not sure if i have to put the query in a thread and 
implement a loop so that i can poll regularly to update the progress 
bar. I guess, i am not sure, how to query regularly - will it go in 
the main thread or be implemented as a runnable - the mechanism i am 
not clear. 
2. If i have to support multiple file downloads, then do i have to 
launch each one of them in it's own thread? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are building on 2.3 and above you don't need to, it automatically displays it in the status bar. Do it like this,
Code from commonsware,

```
    private static final int DOWNLOAD_SUCCESSFUL = 100;
private static final int DOWNLOAD_FAILED = 99;
    private DownloadManager mgr=null;
```

on create do this,

```
`mgr = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);    

        registerReceiver(onComplete,
                 new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
```

`

Then on the click event of the file download,

`lastDownload = 
            mgr.enqueue(new DownloadManager.Request(uri)
                                    .setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI |
                                                                                    DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                                    .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
                                    .setTitle("Test File")
                                    .setDescription("Download zipped file.")
                                    .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
                                            file_name));`

And then a broadcast receiver for when your donwnload compeletes,

```
BroadcastReceiver onComplete=new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {

            findViewById(R.id.start).setEnabled(true);  

            File unzipFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),file_name);            

            //check for new file download
            //extract if it's a new download

            if (unzipFile.exists()) {
                new UnzipFile().execute();              
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Download not found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }           
        }
    };`
```

Comment: On HoneyComb, i can only see only one download (the active download) in the status bar. On Android 2.3.3 device, i see the total number of downloads in the status bar, but only one (or sometimes 2 utmost) active download progress bar is being shown in the status bar. I would rather show the progress bar on each of my download. The client may be downloading upto 4 or 5 files at a time. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Then you have to do it manually, checking the size files and the actual transfer amount of each file. I suggest doing it in a service.